# In Casino Royale, what Exactly does Bond say at this moment?

Tags: dialogue, james-bond, casino-royale

After checking out some guys like Alex Dimitrios and Le Chiffre using M's credential's, he gets out in the Evening to play poker with the Alex. But, before starting his game he says something to two guys (whose car was parked earlier by Bond himself while entering The Ocean Club) at the Drink's table.
What exactly does he say at this moment?

[image]

Comment: What do the subtitles say?

Comment: Don't think it's English. Perhaps one of our European members can translate. It's [here](http://vimeo.com/22216347) at 32:22, right after Bond orders his large Mount Gay with soda.

Comment: @Keen no subtitles at that point... i even tried seeing some srt files to look out for anything. Maybe, as Mary Jo Finch said, it might be german from a brit.

Answer (score 11):

Could be "good evening" in [German](http://translate.google.com/#en/de/good%20evening) (Google pronunciation - it's a bit mechanical). Compare to Bond in this [video](http://vimeo.com/22216347) at 32:22. Really hard to tell.

Comment: As a European, I can confirm he says 'Guten Abend', it's not that bad pronounced, it's just German spoken by a Brit.
FYI Not all Europeans speak German ;)

Comment: @origin Thanks for that! I wasn't sure it was German, so a good guess!

Comment: From the accent of those two guys it seems they are indeed implied to be Germans, so it is pretty likely that he says *"Guten Abend"*. And I also believe to remember that he (or rather his native-speaking pendant) says that in the dubbed German version (though until watching it recently I always thought he just says *"good evening"* in the original).

Comment: Well, it is a short version of "Guten Abend", written " 'n Abend", meaning the same (good evening).

Answer (score 4):

He says guten almond...joke on good evening to the German guys whose rover he crashed and the almonds he had just snacked on.

Comment: Simply "good almonds" that's what I heard too, even with my rusty German. Although I think in German almond is mandel.

Comment: Don't understand the 'low quality' flags raised on this - its a perfectly good if short answer.  If you think its wrong, please downvote rather than flag.